How to customize the css of ActiveAdmin gem?
The back end added the gem ActiveAdmin on my website (version 1.1.0), but I don't find the css file to edit the colors and the design.
Where is it?
I checked on the assets folders but nothing. I also try to search about classes used. How is it possible?

Active Admin 1.1? That was released 7 years ago and is 2 major versions behind the current version.

ActiveAdmin is an engine, so the CSS/SCSS files are in the gem under app/stylesheets/active_admin. To override the contents of these files copy them to the same location in your own project then make edits.

Me too was thinking it... but there is no active_admin css/scss file there

Are you looking at the gem sources as of v1.1? The current version of the gem uses Tailwind. My fork will continue using CSS as before.
